How to make WSL see androidNDK
I'm trying to make an APK file, but for some reason WSL doesn't download the NDK itself.
Error message:
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4 
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk 
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 25b 
# Android NDK is missing, downloading 
# Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r25b-linux.zip 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module> 
sys.exit(main()) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main 
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:]) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1024, in run_command 
self.target.run _commands(args) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 93, in run_commands 
func(args) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug 
self.buildozer.prepare_for_build() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 172, in prepare_for_build 
self.target .install_platform() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 615, in install_platform 
self._install_android_ndk() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 438, in _install_android_ndk 
self.buildozer.download (url, 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 658, in download 
urlretrieve(url, filename, report_hook) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1848, in retrieve 
block = fp.read (bs) 
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tempfile.py", line 622, in func_wrapper 
return func(*args, **kwargs) 
ValueError: read of closed file 
root@DESKTOP-MAB8ONE:~#

I've already tried downloading it myself and putting it in a folder with a .spec file - it doesn't see it.
